# How to sort a list of points nearest to a given point (latitude and longitude)?

Tags: android, collections, rx-java, rx-java2

I have List of Points where each of them have properties latitude and longitude, How I need to sort  a list of points nearest to a given point.
One of the solutions go over the list using for() loop and compare each point with the given point(given current location).
I'm using RxJava2 in android , I see methods toSortedList() which works with Comparator which I thing isn't the way to achieve the solution,
Is there any way using compareTo() method and have the solution.

```
   .map(new Function<List<Point>, List<Point>>() {
                @Override
                public List<StoreModel> apply(List<Point> storeModels) throws Exception {
//...sort list
return storeModels;
                }
            })
```

Comment: A Comparator is pretty much the standard way to sort any list.

Comment: you need to share complete code of this class.There are many ways to sort the latitude and longitude,

Comment: @Gabe Sechan but using Comparator is sorting list by comparing pairs of list, in my case I want to sort list comparing with the given latitude and longitude which values is not included in list,that is why I think about for loop which  I don't like,

Comment: A comparator can compare using anything you want. It's a function you define

Answer (score 0):

as @Gabe Sechan mention, `Comparator` is the standard way, you can compare it to an external value, that does not really matter, as `Comparator` just need to know about giving 2 items what's the quantitative comparison between them.
so `toSortedList()` with `Comparator` it can be something like this:

```
somePointsObservable.toSortedList((p1, p2) -> 
                     calculateDistance(givenPoint, p1) - calculateDistance(givenPoint, p2));
```

where `calculateDistance` calculates the distance between 2 points, and 
`givenPoint` is the current given location you are comparing against.